# JEditorPane does not work properly, if i implement it, then everything goes wrong

Tags: java, browser, jeditorpane

I am in chalange with my friend to make a better program, he decided to make a pain tool, while i decided to make a web browser. I am currently trying to implement the fields. if i add an address bar and a button everything works as told, but when i put a JEditorPane then the display does not show what it is told to show.

CODE with no JEditorPane(everything works):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class browserPannel
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        browser.setSize(1000,700);
        browser.setVisible(true);
        browser.setResizable(false);

        JTextField url = new JTextField();
        url.setSize(890,30);
        url.setVisible(true);
        url.setLocation(15,15);

        JPanel holder = new JPanel();
        holder.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        holder.setSize(1000,700);

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setSize(75,30);
        send.setVisible(true);
        send.setLocation(906,15);

        //JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        //htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        //htmlc.setEditable(true);
        //htmlc.setContentType("text/html");
        //htmlc.setSize(500,500);
        //htmlc.setVisible(true);
        //htmlc.setLocation(15,50);




        holder.add(url);
        holder.add(send);
        //holder.add(htmlc);
        browser.getContentPane().add(holder);
    }
}
```

IMAGE With no JEditorPanehttp, everything works as told: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hONs3.png

CODE With JEditorPane (everything does not work as told):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class browserPannel
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        browser.setSize(1000,700);
        browser.setVisible(true);
        browser.setResizable(false);

        JTextField url = new JTextField();
        url.setSize(890,30);
        url.setVisible(true);
        url.setLocation(15,15);

        JPanel holder = new JPanel();
        holder.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        holder.setSize(1000,700);

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setSize(75,30);
        send.setVisible(true);
        send.setLocation(906,15);

        JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        htmlc.setEditable(true);
        htmlc.setContentType("text/html");
        htmlc.setSize(500,500);
        htmlc.setVisible(true);
        htmlc.setLocation(15,50);




        holder.add(url);
        holder.add(send);
        holder.add(htmlc);
        browser.getContentPane().add(holder);
    }
}
```

IMAGE With JEditorPane, everything does not work as told: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ayeP.png

I Tried removing some of the .set's and i hav tried looking onine, i have also tried only running the JEditorPpane on its own, but i cant seem to set variables for it(such as location, size, etc.)

Comment: On the `JFrame`, invoke `add()`, `pack()` _then_ `setVisible()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting problems because the `FlowLayout` manager, which is the default layout manager for `JPanel` is making its own decisions about how the `holder` panel should be managed and it's contents laid out.

- Make use of appropriate layouts.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details
- Start your UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
- Layout, pack and then make your frame visible.
- With content which is likely to exceeded the visible requirements of your window, you should make use of `JScrollPane`s.  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

[image: Editor Window]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BrowserPannel {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JTextField url = new JTextField(20);

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");

        JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        htmlc.setEditable(true);
        htmlc.setContentType("text/html");

        header.add(url);
        header.add(send);
        browser.getContentPane().add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        browser.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(htmlc));

        browser.pack();
        browser.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does putting the setPack and the setVisible in the button of the code, or does it not have any effect in preformance?

and how could i make the JTextField expand with the expantion of the JFrame?

Comment: It won't affect the performance, but will make components you add to the frame visible when the frame is first made visible, otherwise you will need to call `validate` on the frame to force it to update, which will cause a performance hit.  To expand the `JTextField` across the frame, you need to use a different layout manager.  Something like `GridBagLayout` will do the job.